# Sata Card for OpenSolaris, no raid needed

Tags: raid, opensolaris, sata

can anyone recommend a Sata pci or pci-e card that is compatible with OpenSolaris? Raid isn't necessary as aim is to use ZFS.

**I ended up getting:**
 - Intel sasuc8i (based on LSI 1068)
 - Dell 5/i SAS (Dell code UCS-51)
 - Sil3124 based card

Both are very cheap(sil3124 ~$50, Dell $25 including cables), 4 port and work reasonably well using OpenSolaris build 132. The Dell card doesn't always play nice on Intel chipset boards. It requires taping pins 5-6 from the pci-e connector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best if you check the [OpenSolaris Hardware Compatibility Page](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/hcl/data/os/components/views/disk_controller_all_results.page1.html) before you purchase HW.

Answer (score 3):

Supermicro makes an [add-on PCI-X card](http://www.supermicro.com/products/accessories/addon/AOC-SAT2-MV8.cfm) that uses the same chipset as the X4540/Thumpers and people seem to have good success with it. Supermicro also has a [PCI-e version](http://www.supermicro.com/products/accessories/addon/AOC-SASLP-MV8.cfm), but I haven’t heard anything as far as compatibility.